# Rails form_for with namespaced model names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, namespaces

I have a nested resource `projects/tasks/new` with a `form_for` but I can't figure out how to automatically generate the desired URL:

```
module Projects
  class Project < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :tasks
  end
end

module Projects
  class Task < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :project
  end
end

# in view files
<%= form_for [@project, @task] do |f| %> # => produces URL of projects_project_tasks_path
```

What I want the URL to be is `project_tasks_path`, but the `form_for` is using the namespaced `Projects::Project` as the URL prefix.

The solution I have at the moment is having separate `new.html.erb` and `edit.html.erb` view files that manually specify the URL:

```
# new.html.erb
<%= form_for @task, url: project_tasks_path(@project) do |f| %>
  <%= render "form", f: f %>
<% end %>

# edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @task, url: project_task_path(@project, @task) do |f| %>
  <%= render "form", f: f %>
<% end %>
```

This works but is duplicating unnecessary code.  Note that I am using nested resources for both new and edit actions, as I have to have project context on the task resource.

How do I have the `form_for` produce the desired URL and have a single `form.html.erb` file instead of 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do it by overriding the model name:

```
class Projects::Project < ApplicationRecord
  def model_name
    ActiveModel::Name.new(self, nil, "Project")
  end
end

class Projects::Task < ApplicationRecord
  def model_name
    ActiveModel::Name.new(self, nil, "Task")
  end
end
```

This changes `Projects::Project.model_name.param_key` which is the attribute used for the url generation from `projects_project` to `project`.

See:

- [ActiveModel::Name](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Name.html)

Comment: This works, but I wonder if there's a cleaner way than updating every model?  I know I can do some quick metaprogramming and create a concern/module that overrides this...I just assumed there was a conventional way of doing this. Thanks!

Comment: You can do it in the superclass instead of in each class.